# Universal package publish task in Azure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I have a Azure artifacts project scoped feed. From one of the repo I am publishing the dlls to this feed via pipeline, say X. And another pipeline,Y is utilizing the feed to build their application.
Earlier we had only 3 dlls in the feed published from X. Now we have 5 more dlls to be published from X. I didnt make any change in the pipeline X, thinking that automatically it will fetch all the latest dlls. But the feed is having only 3dlls even after publishing the files to feed using Universal publish task.

Also, I have observed that, Initially I had set version to "Next minor". So the version in the feed is showing 0.1.0. It hasnt change ever since, even though I changed to "Next Major" or "Patch" to test if either of it works. But it doesnt take the latest dlls.

Any idea what is wrong in the pipeline setup?

Edit:
I have added the screenshot of the yaml settings for Universal publish
[image]

Comment: Hello there, please check whether my answer below can help you. If not, please edit your question and provide more detailed information, such as task definition, task log of a run, package version screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you re-run [Universal Package task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/universal-packages?view=azure-devops) with **publish** command, it will generate a new package version. So you're in an unexpected situation.

Since you haven't given any more detailed information (task definition, task log of a run, package version screenshots), I can't tell what is wrong in your pipeline setup, but only some troubleshooting advice:

1. I think the most likely cause is that you are downloading a specific version of the package. **If you want to download the newest package, you need to set `vstsPackageVersion` to `*`.** Here is an example:

   ```
   - task: UniversalPackages@0
     inputs:
       command: 'download'
       downloadDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
       feedsToUse: 'internal'
       vstsFeed: '{feed}' # {project}/{feed}
       vstsFeedPackage: '{package}'
       vstsPackageVersion: '*'
   ```
2. Here is an example of the publish Universal Package task. Please note that:

- the `command` should set to `publish`.
- the `publishDirectory` should point to the folder that contains your dlls.

  ```
  - task: UniversalPackages@0
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      publishDirectory: '$(System.defaultworkingdirectory)'
      feedsToUsePublish: 'internal'
      vstsFeedPublish: '{feed}' # {project}/{feed}
      vstsFeedPackagePublish: '{package}'
      versionOption: 'minor'
  ```

3. Please check the log of your publish artifact task. It will tell you which version of the package was published and whether it was successful.
4. Please go to Artifact. Select your feed and click on your package.

   [image]

   Then switch to the "Versions" tab to check versions of this packages and their publish date. If there are multiple versions that beyond 0.1.0, then we can narrow down the issue to the download universal artifact task.

**Update:**

1. Please select "settings" of your task. Re-choose your "Destination Feed" and "Package name". Then re-add it. After that, try to re-run your pipeline to check the issue.

   [image]
2. Even if the pipeline task runs successfully, the package may not be published correctly. Does your log shows the publish is successful? You can search `success` to see if there is corresponding content.
   If not, please set [System.debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemdebug) to `true` and re-run your pipeline to get detailed debug log.
3. If the above method still does not solve the issue, I suggest you do some tests to verify the scope of the issue. For example, will the issue exist if you use a new artifact? Will the issue exist if you copy the pipeline to a new one?

Comment: Thank you Jane for the detailed explanation. I have followed the above and set up the pipeline. When I check the versions of the packages, its showing only one , which was the first package that was published in the initial run of the pipeline. after that, nothing has been pushed. I am unable to trace why its not pushing to the feed, when the pipeline is showing success

Comment: Also, in the logs its clearly showing publishing package: <feed name> version:2.0

Comment: @Asterix Hello Asterix, I have updated my answer~

Comment: Thanks Jane! Yes, rerunning it after adding settings again did fix it!!